# How to create multiplied flying object effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

How can I create the flying ripped clothing effect like on this picture?

[image: Photoshop Partical Effect]

Is there a simpler way than editing each part manually?

Comment: It seems like you already know the answer; the use of smart objects would make modifications easier, but you're still going to have to do the  initial manual leg work. What other sort of work flow are you expecting to find?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm used to work with video editing softwares, in which one object can be multiplied in different angles, sizes spread etc just like Photoshop brush. I was hoping that I can do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do similar to this with a technique known as [Dispersion Effect](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dispersion%20Effect%20photoshop&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Most of the time its used along with the people so they look like they're disintegrating into some sort of "particle" (paint splatters, dots, smoke, etc).

How I might set this up with your example is copying the clothing patterns onto a few new layers. Scale and rotate each different. No skin though.

Then you'd need to find a suitable brush or create your own set. In this case I'd try to find some sort of "torn fabric" brushes. Add a layer mask to each of your pattern layers and invert it so nothing is showing. Use a solid black torn fabric brush to start painting it back in how you want it. I'd probably mask the people as well so I could have at least a few pieces of the fabric behind them for greater effect with depth.

The models in your example might even be in plain white clothing and the pattern was added to them as well. If you need to do that you'd want to look into [Displacement Maps](https://www.google.com/search?q=displacement%20maps%20photoshop&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) at least for the part that is still attached to them so it has somewhat accurate lighting.